# .NET Core console application as daemon on Debian

Tags: linux, shell, debian, .net-core, daemon

I am trying to run my .NET Core console application as a daemon on a Debian OS, but it seems that the `start-stop-daemon` function doesn't starts the process. I can't figure out why.

```
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

NAME=project-login
DESC="Project Login Server"
DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/dotnet
DAEMON_ARGS=/var/project/Project/src/Project.Login/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/Project.Login.dll
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
PROJECT_BINARY=/var/project/Project/binary

do_start()
{
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background --make-pidfile --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null || return 1
    start-stop-daemon --chdir $PROJECT_BINARY --start --quiet --background --make-pidfile --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS || return 2
}

do_stop()
{
    echo "stop"
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        do_start
        ;;
    stop)
        do_stop
        ;;
    restart)
        do_stop
        do_start
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: project-login [start|stop|restart]"
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
exit 0
```

I've done:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
/etc/init.d/project-login start
```

When I start the service, it writes me that it has started, but in `htop` I can't see any `dotnet` process running. Am I missing something or should I use Docker instead of daemons?

#### File *Project.Login.csproj*

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyTitle>Project.Login</AssemblyTitle>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>Project.Login</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>Project.Login</PackageId>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;win7-x64;osx.10.10-x64;ubuntu.14.04-x64;ubuntu.14.10-x64;ubuntu.15.04-x64;ubuntu.15.10-x64;ubuntu.16.04-x64;ubuntu.16.10-x64;centos.7-x64;debian.8-x64;fedora.23-x64;fedora.24-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <!--<PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dnxcore50</PackageTargetFallback>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.0.4</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>-->
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project.Core\Project.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project.Database\Project.Database.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Ether.Network" Version="1.1.7" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: What's your app type? What's the `project.json` looks like?

Comment: It's a socket server console application. I've posted my `.csproj` file since I am developing the solution on Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Does it run using the publish output when calling `dotnet publish` and using the output from the publish folder? when you do `dotnet build`, the `deps.json` file will reference dll files from the user's nuget cache which may not be accessible to the daemon user.

Comment: I tried with the publish option and the Release option and still the same.
I noticed that when I remove the `--quiet --background` options the app starts and start listening for incoming connection... But I want that behavior in background mode ...